# How to filter view results by currently logged-in user's (NOT AUTHOR'S) role?

Tags: views

I have a view which displays node titles. Each node has different role assigned. Currently no matter what role user has, he sees all the node titles. How do I filter view results, so that it would only display nodes, which has the current user's role only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Filter criteria, you can choose current user, with the help of which you can filter view with current logged in user.